# Receiving NAs when scraping links (href) with rvest

Tags: r, web, screen-scraping, rvest

I have seen some similar questions, but none of the solutions are working for me. I'm trying to get the urls of the links of each of the nodes, but list is only null values.

```
beer <- read_html("https://www.beeradvocate.com/lists/top/")

beerLink <- beer %>% 
html_nodes(".hr_bottom_light a b") %>% 
html_attr('href') %>% 
as.data.frame()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` is a descendant node, but `a` contains the links you want. You can search around for some descendant patterns (I am only familiar with `xpath` versions, and it seems you prefer CSS), but this alternative gets the links you want without that:

```
#using a stub to facilitate accessing the URLs later with
#  an absolute address
stub = 'https://www.beeradvocate.com'
beer <- read_html(paste0(stub, '/lists/top/'))
lnx = beer %>% html_nodes('a') %>% html_attr('href') %>%
  #this pattern matches beer profile links --
  #  the first . is a brewery ID, the second .
  #  is a beer ID within that brewery
  grep('profile/.*/.*/', ., value = TRUE) %>%
  paste0(stub, .)
head(lnx)
# [1] "https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/23222/78820/"  
# [2] "https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/28743/136936/"
# [3] "https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/28743/146770/" 
# [4] "https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/28743/87846/" 
# [5] "https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/863/21690/"    
# [6] "https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/17981/110635/"
```

Also, Abraxas is an amazing beer and Santana album